# How to get value taken from controls

Tags: java, javafx, return-value

I have two class `AddContractController` and `AddContractLogic`. 
I get value from controles in function `setValueControls` and everything is okey. I print values and i gets values. However in the same class i'd use these values in the new function. How to I can receive access to variables from `setValueControls` function. I tried several way but i receive exception NullPinterException because these variables are initiated only during after click button.

```
package com.controller;

import com.logic.AddContractLogic;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class AddContractController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private DatePicker contractDatePicker;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton contractRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton agreementRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private Spinner<Double> provisionSpinner;

    @FXML
    private TextField nameContractField;

    @FXML
    private Label statusLabel;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup toggleGroup1;



    SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory spinner = new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(1,400,12.5);


    public DatePicker getContractDatePicker() {
        return contractDatePicker;
    }

    public RadioButton getContractRadioButton() {
        return contractRadioButton;
    }

    public RadioButton getAgreementRadioButton() {
        return agreementRadioButton;
    }

    public Spinner<Double> getProvisionSpinner() {
        return provisionSpinner;
    }

    public TextField getNameContractField() {
        return nameContractField;
    }

    public Label getStatusLabel() {
        return statusLabel;
    }

    public ToggleGroup getToggleGroup1() {
        return toggleGroup1;
    }





    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        provisionSpinner.setValueFactory(spinner);
        provisionSpinner.setEditable(true);

        toggleGroup1 = new ToggleGroup();
        contractRadioButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup1);
        agreementRadioButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup1);
        contractRadioButton.setSelected(true);
    }

    @FXML
    public void actionAfterClick(){
        AddContractLogic logic = new AddContractLogic();
        logic.setValueControls(this);
    }
}
```

```
package com.logic;

import com.controller.AddContractController;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddContractLogic {





    public  void setValueControls(AddContractController add){

        LocalDate date = add.getContractDatePicker().getValue();
        System.out.println(date);

        double provisionValue = add.getProvisionSpinner().getValue();
        System.out.println(provisionValue);

        String textContract = add.getNameContractField().getText();
        System.out.println(textContract);

        boolean isAgreement = add.getAgreementRadioButton().isSelected();
        System.out.println(isAgreement);

        boolean isContract = add.getContractRadioButton().isSelected();
        System.out.println(isContract);


    }

}
```

Comment: "How to I can receive access to variables from setValueControls function" you mean you want to get `textContract` for example ? Make it a class variable `private String textContract;`   and add a getter `String getTextContract(){ return textContract; }`  for more help post [mcve] and the full exception stack trace.

Comment: You may also want to look into passing an object around instead of the controller. For example public class Contract {} which has it's fields (or properties if all out fx) bound to the control values.  Then your logic controller accepts the contract object instead of the controller. Downstream saving and validation will be better as well.